# Ant does not load jar - custom Java build

Tags: java, jar, ant, noclassdeffounderror

I am seeking assistance troubleshooting an issue where Ant does not load a jar file properly.
I am working with a huge codebase that has a 2,500 line build.xml for ant. It is run by a custom command:

./ant run-registry

and then

./ant run-myComponent

Originally, I had the error below. I fixed it by editing the build file, which had some errors in the line `"<pathelement path='${build.lib.dir}/java-naoqi-sdk-2.5.5.5-linux64.jar'/>",` such as a misplaced curly bracket (such is life as a CS major!).

```
running:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/***/***/build
    [javac] /home/***/***/com/pepper/PepperComponentImpl.java:27: error: package com.aldebaran.qi does not exist
    [javac] import com.aldebaran.qi.Application;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /home/***/***/com/pepper/PepperComponentImpl.java:28: error: package com.aldebaran.qi.helper.proxies does not exist
```

But once I fixed this I got a new error!

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aldebaran/qi/Application
     [java]     at com.pepper.PepperComponentImpl.
     [java] (PepperComponentImpl.java:65)
```

So it is recognizing the jar, but not finding a definition for the class Application? This class is declared in the jar, and I made sure by clicking on the jar that com/aldebaran/qi/Application.class was a file that exists. It is!

The jar is in home/projectName/jars, and is loaded into the ant build as follows. This is also how myComponent, "pepperComponent," is loaded:

```
Line 188
  <path id='pepper.classpath'>
    <path refid='base.classpath'/>
    <pathelement path='${build.lib.dir}/java-naoqi-sdk-2.5.5.5-linux64.jar'/>
  </path>
Line 646
  <target name='pepper' depends='init, core' extensionOf='java-only' description='Builds the java-only pepper components.'>
    <build-java package.dir='com/pepper' classpath='pepper.classpath'/>
  </target>
Line 1799
  <target name='run-peppercomponent' depends='pepper' description='PepperComponent'>
    <run-component component='com.pepper.PepperComponent'
                   args='${component.pepperComponent.additionalargs}'
                   local.ip='${component.pepperComponent.localIP}'
                   registry.ip='${component.pepperComponent.registry.ip}'>
    </run-component>
  </target>
```

I don't understand how this build file works well enough to understand why it doesn't see the jar.
Does anyone else have some idea what's going on? Thank you for reading!

Comment: If your class is in the jar you have to add the jar you want in the path

Comment: My class actually isn't in the jar, there are two com folders. Which is confusing- but we have project/com/pepper in the main directory for my class, and then com/aldebaran is a totally separate thing that exists inside the jar. As for adding the jar in the path, I think the line with pathelement path = Java-naoqi...jar did the job. But it still fails.

Comment: Do you compile all the classes in order to add them in the build path?

Comment: I think so. The build file was made over a series of years to encompass the entire codebase. How would I check to make sure?